# VIM - FuzzyFinder closes on Backspace, why?

Tags: vim, fuzzyfinder

I use FuzzyFinder in VIM (cannot switch to Command-T, no Ruby support on my server). It works well, except for one issue: Whenever I hit backspace (for example, after making a typo), the entire FuzzyFinder buffer just closes.

This doesn't happen every time, only right after entering a directory. For example:

- `FILE>filename` -- I can hit backspace just fine, and get `FILE>filenam`
- `FILE>folder/` -- if I hit backspace now, the buffer just closes. It's as if I can't navigate backwards in the hierarchy after entering a directory.

I have no idea why this happens, and it's driving me crazy. Any advice would be appreciated.

This also happens when I press Ctrl+w as it says in the fuf documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using FuzzyFinder for a while and never faced this problem.

Possible you have some mapping that may be interfering with FuzzyFinder. You could try `:map <bs>` to find out if there is any mapping on backspace key, and `:10verbose map <bs>` to find out where such mapping was set.

You also could try `:unmap <bs>` and `:unmap! <bs>` to remove any mappings from backspace and check if the issue still exists.

If the above doesn't solve the problem you might consider contacting the plugin author, as the issue could also be related to some other mapping, as stated on FuzzyFinder changelog, `:h fuf-changelog`:

```
  - Fixed the bug that it did not work correctly when a user have mapped <C-p>
    or <Down>.
```